# Where is the correct location for an AJAX call in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone.js for a new app I'm building.

I need to perform an AJAX call to get more properties for my model object (image, title & description of a book).

Where is the correct place for this call? In the Model, View or somewhere else? specifically related to Backbone.js MVC model.

**Additional Info**

I'm using LocalStorage and not a server. The AJAX call will be to a web service API and constitutes only part of my actual model data.

Comment: Does anyone have a simple example? I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now and have looked all over. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have properly configured your model you can just call `model.fetch()` which will issue a HTTP GET to whatever `url` you have configured and refresh the model with the results from the server.

Comment: Ah sorry I should have ben clearer. I'm using LocalStorage and not a server. The AJAX call is from a web service API ( Google Book Search actually).

Comment: Okay, in that case just use jQuery's `$.get()` function to get the data and then add those values into your model.

Comment: My question is where do I do that call? In the model or view?

Comment: I would encapsulate that call as a function in the model but call it from the view.